# Node value returns null for a XML Input

Tags: xml, vba, excel, nodevalue

GETTING ERROR for the below macro script. Need extract date, name and address in a single table. Since there is only one value of date, the second value returns null.

However I need the same value to be present in all records of extract date

```
Set ApplicationsNode = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/Extract/Applications/Application")
Set extractnodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/Extract/ExtractDate")
Set NameNode = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/Extract/Applications/Application/Name/text()")
Set AddrNode = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/Extract/Applications/Application/Addr/text()")

For i = 0 To (ApplicationsNode.Length - 1)

    Extract = extractnodes(i).NodeValue
    Name = NameNode(i).NodeValue
    Addr = AddrNode(i).NodeValue

    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i + 2).Value = Extract
    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i + 2).Value = Name
    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i + 2).Value = Addr

Next
```

Input XML:

```
 <Extract>
     <ExtractDate>2018-02-21 10:01:01</ExtractDate>
       <Applications>
          <Application>         
             <Name>1234</Name>
             <Addr>700ST</Addr>
          </Application>    
       <Application>            
            <Name>123466</Name>
            <Addr>277AVD</Addr>
       </Application>
       <Applications>
      </Extract>
```

Comment: what error? where?

Comment: Also, the XML is malformed.  Last line should be `</Application> </Applications> </Extract>`

Comment: Run time error - 91 : Object variable or with block variable not set

errors occurs in  
Extract = extractnodes(i).NodeValue ; since the node value returns empty from input XML

Comment: error on which line?

Comment: error on line 6:

Extract = extractnodes(i).NodeValue

Comment: updated the input XML;

My results should be as below. This is how it looks in the table.

extract date--name--addr

Comment: @Raja, Fix your malformed xml snippet that ashleedawg has already pointed out. I believe, you are here to seek a solution not to confuse others with the portion of elements you have pasted above.

Comment: I've already tidied up your code myself once...  After you fix it, does the error still occur?  If so, what is the value of the related variable(s) at the time of the error?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below portion of elements within `content.xml` file in desktop and run the below code.

within `content.xml` file:

```
<Extract>
    <ExtractDate>2018-02-21 10:01:01</ExtractDate>
    <Applications>
        <Application>         
            <Name>1234</Name>
            <Addr>700ST</Addr>
        </Application>    
        <Application>            
            <Name>123466</Name>
            <Addr>277AVD</Addr>
        </Application>
    </Applications>
</Extract>
```

Script to parse the value from:

```
Sub DemoXML()
    Dim post As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        .async = False: .validateOnParse = False
        .Load (ThisWorkbook.path & "\content.xml")

        For Each post In .SelectNodes("//Extract//Application")
            r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = post.ParentNode.ParentNode.FirstChild.Text
            Cells(r, 2) = post.SelectNodes(".//Name")(0).Text
            Cells(r, 3) = post.SelectNodes(".//Addr")(0).Text
        Next post
    End With
End Sub
```

Populated results:

```
2/21/2018 10:01 1234    700ST
2/21/2018 10:01 123466  277AVD
```

Comment: Nice! A side question: which is the meaning of the colon after `r=r+1`?

Comment: Using colon you can fit multiple lines in a single line. That is not necessary to use. However, I did it to save the space.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Can you tell the meaning of the statement

               For Each post In .SelectNodes("//Extract//Application")   

                    ***what does the "//" mean ?
                    ***  what happens if I use the FIlename.SelectNode 
                            instead of .SelectNode

Answer (score 0):

Better answer already given but here is a variation:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DemoXML()
    Dim post As Object, R As Long, C As Long, dateString As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
         .async = False: .validateOnParse = False
        .Load "C:\Users\User\Desktop\random.xml"
        dateString = .SelectSingleNode("//ExtractDate").Text

        For Each post In .SelectNodes("//Application")
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = dateString
            Cells(R, 2) = post.FirstChild.Text
            Cells(R, 3) = post.LastChild.Text
        Next post
    End With
End Sub
```